# Symfony 3.4.: Stack trace not shown when error is thrown

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-500

I upgraded my Symfony application to 3.4. 
Whenever a 500 error is thrown and I look it up in the "Response" tab of my Chrome Developer tools, I can only see the error message, but NOT the stack trace.

I have the following setting:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

How can I enable the stack trace? It was shown when I used Symfony 2.

Comment: Why cant you see it in nginx or apache error log? Do you think we should expose error to live users?

Comment: His environment is dev not live @PratikCJoshi

Comment: I want the stack trace to be shown when using the application locally in my dev environment.

Comment: Have you enabled the profiler?